# Google App Engine - Use CloudSQL and Storage GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Please tell me!
If i want use CloudSQL and Storage, i need enable billing and pay for my service?
Dont have free price for use little?

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate billing: [Cloud Sql Pricing](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/billing), [Google Cloud Storage Pricing](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricing-and-terms).  There is a small free tier for Storage, but none for CloudSQL.

Comment: Oh, but if i'm not 18 age, i dont have Master Card, Visa card, What can i do for enable billing...

Comment: Hrm.  Get a gift-card style credit card?  The card providers supposedly guarantee that vendors can't tell the difference between these and an "actual" credit card.